# SQL Querying Incomplete Result

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am having trouble understanding what is wrong with this query or how to properly join it together.

I know that I am missing results from other queries that show both sides of the connections separately using two aliases for the same table.

Pretty much a friendship has two "id"s (source and target) which both map to the same column in the users table.

I believe it is the OR statement that is causing the invalid joining, and if so how is the joining suppose to be done. If not what is the problem?

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
  FROM friendships AS f, users AS u
  WHERE f.mutual = 'true' -- both are friends
  AND (u.id = f.source_id OR u.id = f.target_id) -- this line?
  AND f.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-20' AND '2016-01-27' -- time period they became friends
  GROUP BY u.id, u.first_name
  ORDER BY u.first_name;
```

Is it the use of the word "DISTINCT?"

I appreciate the help, I have tried INNER and LEFT JOINS, but my mind is just blanking on this and I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Here is the query that IS WORKING and shows me more users than the above query:

```
SELECT f.source_id, u1.first_name AS s_firstname, u1.last_name AS s_lastname, f.target_id, u2.first_name AS t_firstname, u2.last_name AS t_lastname
  FROM friendships AS f, users AS u1, users AS u2
  WHERE f.mutual = 'true' 
  AND u1.id = f.source_id AND u2.id = f.target_id
  AND f.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-20' AND '2016-01-27';
```

***Friendship Table Definition:***

[image]

***User Table Definition:***

[image]

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no aggregate functions? Also the general GROUP BY rule says: "If a `GROUP BY` clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."If you follow that rule, you'll be safe. (Combining `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` isn't for beginners...)

Comment: I was using GroupBy to check the users more easily, and I removed it to see if that was the problem and the same results showed up.

Comment: Can you add table definitions, sample table data and expected result?

Comment: The table definitions are fairly large and these are the most simple forms of the queries I could make without changing the results and duplicating the problem. the first name and last names are all read data.  I would rather wait to see if anyone can get this or I'll figure it out on my own tomorrow. Could you check the `OR` statement where I expect the problem is. I believe self joining that OR might be the problem?

Comment: Use either `GROUP BY` but with **all** fields, or `DISTINCT`. Not both.

Comment: I removed GROUP BY and left DISTINCT and still was missing results.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should stop using those outdated, ancient implicit joins in the `where` clause and use a proper explicit `JOIN` clause

Comment: The second query IS correct and it is separating the users into 2 groups (source and target) -- (source_id, source_name, target_id, target_name) and they are being display as a "friendship" aka connection, so two users on one row. I want to display those users in one collection (id, first, last) to get a complete list (one user on one row). Which is what the first query is doing but missing some of the users. Therefore I want DISTINCT users from the friendships. Another way of saying it:  I want the `u.id` to come from `f.source_id OR f.target_id` but I think this might be incorrectly stated.

Comment: What is the role of mutual? What table is it in? Does friendship just contain source & target columns?

Comment: It just symbols a two way acceptance or connection. So that source_id and target_id have accepted each other. It is just false until both users have accepted each other. mutual is in friendship as well as source_id and target_id (all as columns)

Comment: From your comments, it seems like you thought you had tried the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either
 1. UNION (distinct) the projections of your second query on source and target or
 2. select distinct users where they are a source or target

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM friendships AS f, users AS u
WHERE f.mutual = 'true' -- both are friends
AND (u.id = f.source_id OR u.id = f.target_id)
AND f.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-20' AND '2016-01-27'
ORDER BY u.first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid any "duplicates" between u1 * u2. Either one (*or more*) friendship records exist (in the given period) or they don't.

```
SELECT u1.first_name AS s_firstname, u1.last_name AS s_lastname
        , u2.first_name AS t_firstname, u2.last_name AS t_lastname
  FROM users AS u1
  JOIN users AS u2
        ON EXISTS (
        SELECT 13 FROM friendships  f
        WHERE u1.id = f.source_id AND u2.id = f.target_id
        AND f.mutual = 'true'
        AND f.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-20' AND '2016-01-27';
        );
```